# saving a file on server using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xml

This code works, in that it runs without error:-

```
//  and send data to the server
sfname = "emptydeck02.xml";
$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "deck_data/" + sfname,
  dataType: "xml",
  data: xmlv,
  success: function() {
    alert(sfname+" saved");
  },
  error: function() {
    alert("An error occurred while saving XML file.");
  }

});
```

Can anyone please help resolve these issues?

1. Why does this code not update emptydeck02.xml on the server?
2. Why can it not create emptydeck02.xml on the server if it doesn't already exist?
3. I'm suspecting I need some php code on the server but how would this be invoked using my above code?

Note that the deck_data directory has public and group write permissions.

Also, I load xmlv with known xml code that is working when I read it...

Comment: Are there any errors in the console? What handles the update on the server-side? Are there any errors in the server's error logs?

Comment: *I'm suspecting I need some php code on the server*. Well, yes...

Comment: You cannot write that way files on server. You need some php script to process your POST with `file_put_contents`. So url should point to that php file, inside that php grab the content you want to write from the POST data (your `xmlv`)

Comment: rats :-( Please advise me how to invoke the server-side code. so far I only read xml files and that works fine without any php.

Comment: [The AJAX will invoke the PHP code residing at the `url:`](http://jayblanchard.net/basics_of_jquery_ajax.html)

Comment: OK, so the url should be something like "deckwriter.php"? Then how will I pass the file name to be written?

Comment: It's not that simple. You will need a serverside script (whether in PHP or some other language) that can receive the file data and write it to disk on the server; then use that script as your POST url.    If you're not familiar with serverside coding, you may be better off using something like firebase cloud storage or similar, which does most of the work for you  (storing arbitrary file uploads on your server is inherently risky...)

Comment: I discovered that I can pass POST variables as part of my data and have resolved all my php 'issues'. Unfortunately I cannot post my answer as the question has been "put on hold". Never mind, another time perhaps. Thank you to all those who tried to help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are misunderstanding what HTTP is (and isn't), and why people developed things like WebDAV and REST.

HTTP is simply a protocol (agreement that if X is requested, Y will indicate success, Z will indicate failure, etc) for clients (often web browsers) and web servers (e.g. Apache, NGINX, IIS, etc).

When you `POST`, you're simply saying "*I am sending you some data to this resource URI*".  What the web server chooses to do (or not do) with that data is a completely separate concern - and absolutely does **not** mean a file will be created at that URI.

Initially (as is my understanding), HTTP was designed to solve "simple" problem of allowing a client on one end of a TCP network request some data (`GET`).  Subsequent "verbs" (such as `POST`) were introduced to allow formatted data to be pushed back to the other way - then as technology inevitably moved on, technologies like [WebDAV](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebDAV) sought to extend HTTP to behave "more like a filesystem".  (My choice of words, and based only on my very basic understanding of WebDAV's purpose.)

My point is this: HTTP only gives a protocol, it does not imply an *implementation*.  If you want to have your web service (which talks HTTP) allow creation of a file, you would have to have to implement the corresponding web service on the server end too.  (As you say, PHP is one such example language to do this in.)

Security is a huge concern if you're allowing potentially untrusted sources to push data onto your network.  Otherwise if you're generally looking for hinters, I'd suggest you start reading up on PHP (and Apache's `mod_rewrite` if you want to map "virtual" URIs to a single PHP script) or look into WebDAV server implementations, like Apache's [`mod_dav`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_dav.html).

Comment: I discovered that I can pass POST variables as part of my data and have resolved all my php 'issues'. Unfortunately I cannot post my answer as the question has been "put on hold". Never mind, another time perhaps. Thank you to all those who tried to help.